# C# or C++ - Creating fake focus?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi

I was wondering if there was any way through C# or C++ to send to fake or otherwise trick a program into thinking it has focus? I'm thinking that there's a message you can send to it using SendMessage/PostMessage that'll trick it into having focus.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guaranteed way to trick it into thinking it has focus because there are multiple ways it can check if it has focus. For example, it could be checking for `WM_SETFOCUS` and then checking it is out of focus when it receives `WM_KILLFOCUS`. So you could trick it in this case by sending intercepting all `WM_KILLFOCUS` messages with a window hook.

However, it might also be checking for if it has focus by calling `GetFocus`. So to trick it in that scenario, you would need to detour `GetFocus` and fake the return value. You can try both of these methods and they might work and they might not, but I wouldn't expect them to work reliably.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the places where this can go wrong. Also, perhaps less likely, but app could also be using GetGUIThreadInfo (which also returns the currently active/focused thread), GetForegroundWindow or any of several windows APIs that return the current, active, or focused HWND or thread.

Comment: Thanks for the info, guys! I'm working on a prototype right now, though I'm having to test each one individually to see which the program responds too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I hooked `WM_NCACTIVATE` to let the game know that it is still in focus. It worked fine on two games I worked.